# how to check if PPA is already added to apt sources list in a bash script

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

Do someone know how to check if a PPA is already added to my system before i add it with the `add-apt-repository` command in a `shell script`.

That would be very helpful.

Thank you.

Answer (score 14):

You can do something like this:

```
the_ppa=...  # e.g. the_ppa="ondrej/apache2"

if ! grep -q "^deb .*$the_ppa" /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*; then
    # commands to add the ppa ...
fi
```

Notes:

- `grep` exits with success if it finds a match
- The `!` negates this, so the commands will be executed if there is no match = ppa not added
- The `-q` flag makes `grep` *quiet*, so it doesn't print the matched lines. It would be just noise, we need only to know if there is a match or not, for which the exit code is perfect
- The `^deb .*` prefix is to make sure the matched line starts with `deb`, to exclude lines that are commented out

Comment: As it turns out, this will find ppas that have been commented out, but I want to find PPAs that have not been commented out, and @Ten-Coins answer does that.

Answer (score 4):

Open your terminal and type this command

```
grep ^ /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/* | grep fogger
```

replace fogger with PPA name.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Removing list.save files, sources, ensure only deb lines and count it for "fogger" ppa:

```
ppa_added=`grep ^ /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/* | grep -v list.save | grep -v deb-src | grep deb | grep fogger | wc -l`

echo $ppa_added
```

Comment: This also finds `deb` lines that are commented out, starting with `# deb`, and lines from files like `foo-ppa.list.distUpgrade` - is that intended?